# Next element in array of active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Ruby on Rails Next/Previous Post

I have an index page - posts#index which has links to the show pages of each post. Each post references a particular topic and may have been created at different times, so the id's of the posts aren't necessarily sequential for all the posts in that topic. I want to be able to go to the next & previous posts for a particular topic.

In my PostsController I've got instance variables for all the posts for a topic and the particular topic being shown

```
def index
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @posts = @topic.posts.all
end

def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @posts = @topic.posts.all
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
end
```

@posts is an array of active record objects
    `@posts => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [
    #<Post id: 73, topic_id: 3>, 
    #<Post id: 74, topic_id: 3>,
    #<Post id: 76, topic_id: 3>, 
    #<Post id: 77, topic_id: 3>, 
    #<Post id: 91, topic_id: 3>]`

If this was an array of ruby objects I could use `@posts.index(@post)` to find the id of a particular element of the array and then do either `index + 1` or `index - 1` to traverse the array of posts, but `.index` is a different method in active record. If I'm on the show page for any given post in a particular topic, `Post id: 76` for example, how can I go to `link_to Post id: 74` (next) and `link_to Post id: 77` (previous) in a way that work for any post in a particular topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  posts = @topic.posts.order('posts.id ASC')
  @post = posts.find(params[:id])
  @previous_post = posts.where('posts.id < ?', @post.id).first
  @next_post = posts.where('posts.id > ?', @post.id).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is a nice succinct solution to what I needed. I ended up changing .first to .last to get them to cycle correctly.
    `@next_post = posts.where('posts.id > ?', @post.id).first`
to 
    `@next_post = posts.where('posts.id > ?', @post.id).last`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Post.where("id > ?", 74).order(:id).first
```

Or, if you have some topics (not sure about your model), but it will look similar to this:

```
some_topic.posts.where("id > ?", 74).order(:id).first
```

Here the `74` is an ID of the current post.

Comment: posts should be in plural, because it is probably "has_many" relation

Answer (score 0):

There are a few gems to help. I have created one which is quit flexible because it works dynamically with any collection and its order (which is not the case when it's hardcoded like : `Book.where("id > ?", 74).order(:id)`)

The gem is called [nexter](https://github.com/charly/nexter) and it's basic usage is like this :

```
@books = Book.includes(:author).bestsellers.
          order("genre", "authors.name", "published_at desc")

nexter = Nexter.wrap( @books, @books.find(params[:id]) )
nexter.previous
nexter.next
```

See the [README](https://github.com/charly/nexter) for more info.

Comment: This is cool but outside of the scope of what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Hope it will be useful _next_ time :-)